# Use rack to run a get request from within the same Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am trying to find a way to email the result of a request to our app to a user at a specific time early in the morning.  I would like to do it from within the app, and the data returned depends on which user it is and the params of the request.  Can I use Rack and just set up the session and run the get?  How do I do that?  Pointers to any helpful docs on the web.  The app is in Rails 2.3.  Thanks!

Comment: http://codefol.io/posts/14--What-is-Rack-A-Primer is helpful

Comment: Thanks.  I just need to warm up some maple syrup, and I will be very happy!